# Making Command blocks send redstone currents upon player death

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I am making a huge map (Not giving any spoilers!) it's taken me 13.4 days to make this, yet I ran into one problem. When a player dies the redstone still flows.

I was wondering if there is a way for a command block to detect whenever a player dies and be able to make it able to restart?

Comment: "When a player dies, the redstone still flows" What redstone? Who/what triggered that redstone? We need more information in order to solve your question

Comment: Ugh. The Redstone that powers the command blocks to send *cough command blocks to send aggressive items at the player/s

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking for a way to send a redstone current whenever a player is "dead" (died and didn't hit respawn). 
In Minecraft, being "dead" means you have 0 health, right? So all we need is a command to check their health. Luckily, that's pretty easy! All entities (or maybe just mobs, not 100% sure) have a "Health" tag. All we need is a testfor checking if you have 0 health, using this command: 
`/testfor @a {Health:0.0f}`
*What does the 's' mean?*
Health is what is known as a *short*, a type of intsger value used in programming. You may have seen values such as "1b". 'B' stands for *byte*, a similar value, but with a smaller possible value. Bytes can store a number from -256 to 255, and shorts can store a number from -32,768 to 32,767.
**One more thing!** To receive the current, you must have a redstone comparator hooked up to the /testfor command block. 
I hope this is what you are looking for! Just leave a comment or edit your question if this isn't!

Comment: Signed bytes have a range of -128 to 127. Also be aware that this will not work in 1.9+, as `Health` is a float rather than a short. That would be a very simple fix though, as you'd simply declare it as a float (`Health:0.0f`).

Comment: Wait, Health used to be a signed byte? I thought it was a regular one, which just goes to show my command knowledge :)